# Adding ExtJS4 components to ExtJS3 components?

Tags: extjs, sandbox, extjs4, extjs3

I've got an ExtJS3 application which could benefit from the [ExtJS4 SVG stuffs](http://www.sencha.com/blog/ext-js-4-preview-drawing-and-charting/). Online there is an [example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.1/examples/sandbox/sandbox.html) of how to use sandbox mode to include ExtJS4 components in an ExtJS3 application... but in the example the ExtJS4 components are in their own floating [window](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.window.Window), so the ExtJS4 components aren't really added to ExtJS3 components; they just co-exist rather independently.

Is there a way to add an ExtJS4 component to an ExtJS3 component while running in sandbox mode? For example:

```
var item = Ext4.create("Ext.panel.Panel", { // ExtJS4
    /* config */
});
var parent = new Ext.Panel({ // ExtJS3
    items:[item],
    /* more config */
});
```

If I try something like this, I usually get an error like...

```
this.container is null (http://localhost:4000/path/ext-4.0.0/builds/ext-all-sandbox-debug.js:27723)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem that some Ext4 components can `renderTo` DOM elements in Ext3 components, with limited success:

```
var ext3Panel = new Ext.Panel({
    title:'Ext3'
});
ext3Panel.on('afterrender', function() {
    var ext4Panel = Ext4.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        title:'Ext4',
        renderTo:ext3Panel.body.dom,
    });
    ext3Panel.add(ext4Panel);
});
```

This seems to be most useful when using Ext4 charts in an Ext3 project.

Citations:

- [Sencha Forum: ExtJs3 and ExtJs4 in One App](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?127081-ExtJs3-and-ExtJs4-in-One-App)
- [Sencha Forum archives: Using Ext JS 4 Charts in Ext JS 3?](http://www.sencha.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-126391.html?s=883dcae1c09ec820e52fb96c737fe20f)

Comment: Having some problems with the Ext4 charts stuff, input appreciated - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455873/using-extjs-4-charts-in-extjs-3-application

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you're doing is possible. ExtJS 4 has a completely new rendering engine, and so it's looking for a layout container that doesn't exist.

You'd be far better off migrating from ExtJS 3 -> 4.